# Navigation issue in Jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I m developing Mobile Web application using jquery mobile.In a aspx page i m using two jquery mobile pages `(div data-role='page')`. I am using $mobile.changepage for navigation.
But while redirecting some flickering is happening.How to overcome this issue.which one can i use for navigation.

**Page ONE:-**

```
 <div data-role="page" id="one">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Multi-page</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content" >  
    <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"Check\" value="Change" id="1"   disabled=\"true\"  checked=\"true\" onchange='return CheckBand()'/ >
    <label for="1" id=\'2'>Check</label>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-theme="d">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

**Page TWO:-**

```
<div data-role="page" id="dAtAc" data-theme="a">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Two</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">    
    <h2>Two</h2>
    <p>I have an id of "two" on my page container. I'm the second page container in this multi-page template.</p>   
    <p>Notice that the theme is different for this page because we've added a few <code>data-theme</code> swatch assigments here to show off how flexible it is. You can add any content or widget to these pages, but we're keeping these simple.</p>  
    <p><a href="#one" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Back to page "one"</a></p> 

</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

In Page one checkbox onchange event i m calling one function.
       CheckBand()

```
  function CheckBand()
  {
   $.mobile.changePage("#dAtAc", { transition: "slide", allowSamePageTransition: true, changeHash: true});
  }
  1)What do you mean by flickering? -- while navigating 2 to 3 times the page is blinking
  2)Jquery mobile supports a large number of devices and operating systems. Which device, jqm version, browser are you using? Yes correct
  3)Is it on an emulator or an actual device? not in emulator actual device it is web application 
  4)Which transition are using? slide
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by flickering? Jquery mobile supports a large number of devices and operating systems. Which device, jqm version, browser are you using? Is it on an emulator or an actual device? Which transition are using? The default one?

Comment: There's about a billion possibile causes for this, but one thing that has always helped me is using `.ui-page {-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}` - in addition to that it would be highly useful if you could elaborate on question #2 (yes is not an answer in this case, we'd need device, browser & jqm version).

Comment: Sorry @m90 2nd question's answer -->Devices---> 1.Android version 2.3.5 HTC Desire S S510e  2.Android Version 4.0.4 Samsung GT-P5100     2.JQM Version--->1.3.1  3.Default Android browser. In both devices same blinking problem is there.

Comment: And which version of jqm? 1.3.1?

Comment: Please give suggestion to how to overcome from this issue.

Comment: Default Android browser is a shitty browser. In my app I've seen terrible things with it, but when I used another one (etc. dolphin) all the problems where gone. I don't think there is anything you can do.